# C# Listen for checkbox chenge in groupbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, event-handling

I have a groupbox with 16 checkboxes and I need to run an event that knows the button pressed if any of them change states.

I know I can add an on click action for each but is there a cleaner way of doing this?
[image: Showing layout of the 16 buttons]

Comment: I'd be interested to know how you've built out these boxes in the first place. If you're dynamically creating them then you can attach the handler at the same time.

Comment: @Enigmativity What do you mean "how I've built it"? they are just styled check boxes that are placed at compile time.

Comment: You've just drag-and-dropped component using the designer rather than dynamically creating the boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that you can just reuse actions and cast the sender object:

```cs
private void InputSwitched(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle checked events of all the checkboxes of the groupbox, using a single event handler, like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    groupBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
        .ToList().ForEach(c => c.CheckedChanged += C_CheckedChanged);
}
private void C_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var c = (CheckBox)sender;
    MessageBox.Show($"{c.Name} - Checked: {c.Checked}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I meant in the comments about dynamically creating the controls.

You can do something like this:

```
    private List<CheckBox> _checkBoxes = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var checkbox_count = 15;

        _checkBoxes =
                Enumerable
                    .Range(0, checkbox_count)
                    .Select(x => new CheckBox()
                    {
                        Text = $"CheckBox {x}",
                    })
                    .ToList();

        foreach (var checkbox in _checkBoxes)
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(checkbox);
            checkbox.CheckedChanged += (s, e)
                    => checkbox.BackColor =
                        checkbox.Checked
                            ? Color.Red
                            : Color.Blue;
        }
    }
```